# Particle in Oscillating Field

Tags: classical-electrodynamics

Ignoring quantum effects, what are the dynamics of an electrically charged particle placed with zero initial momentum in an oscillating electromagnetic field, e.g. light?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is that the charged particle will oscillate (sinusoidally) in the same direction as the applied electric field. The acceleration and E-field are in phase, but the velocity and E-field are out of phase. In most cases only the electric field needs to be considered because the B-field amplitude of an EM wave is $c$ times smaller than the E-field amplitude. This means that the $ q\,{\bf v} \times {\bf B}$ part of the Lorentz force can be neglected so long as the particle is not accelerated to relativistic velocities.

The particle is of course given kinetic energy by this process, which is removed from the incoming wave. That energy is given back to the surroundings because the oscillating particle radiates in a manner approximated by a classical oscillating electric dipole.

The entire (elastic) process is called "Thomson scattering".

I'll let someone else handle what happens when things get relativistic - outside my area of expertise...